# How to undo xrandr settings?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, xrandr

I had split my screen into two using this:

```
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI-0~1 960/254x1080/286+0+0 HDMI-0
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI-0~2 960/254x1080/286+960+0 none
xrandr --fb 1921x1080
xrandr --fb 1920x1080
```

It worked fine, then I tried "arandr" and saw that I had at least 4 extra (virtual)-monitors on the bottom.

To try and resize one half to a full screen I took the other half out of the Display box, and kept taking the little ones on the bottom, and to test it out I clicked on the "+" icon on the top navbar and bang, my screen went black as if it was disconnected. (I know it's trying to access an out of reach pixles)

If I go to another session (Ctrl+Alt+F3), I can see it's looping with infinite error messages about data link layers or something.

Trying to resolve it, I purged nvidia-*, installed nouveau from the recovery mode, yet nothing happened, so tried "xrandr -s 0" and nothing, and then I did a "dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg", although it seemed to do nothing, and it kept looping with error messages again, at one point it gave up by stating something like it had to reset a non-working stuff or some sort of issue, then all of a sudden I found that I can get back to the System, but it happens every time I reboot all over again.

I couldn't locate a monitors.xml file, nor could it find where did "Arandr" put the messed up config file for the split screen with half of it set outside the Box or the Physical Monitor's reach. It's not on .profile either, so any help to undo that or where is this config set is appreciated a lot.

Thanks.

---

Edit:
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 with Gnome Shell.
It's impossible to boot if I don't go through Alt+Ctrl+F3 then while the looping messages are eating up the screen, I have to log in, then:

**`dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`**

Afterwards, it will break the loop, bring me back to GDM with a Magnified screen where the display moves with the mouse's position, but once I log in, I get back to my working desktop.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
The DE is the default Gnome Shell